# How do you specify the assumptions/types on the elements of a Function or IndexedBase?

Tags: python, sympy

If I have a simple variable, I can specify the assumptions or type as follows:

```
import sympy as sy

k = sy.Symbol('k', integer=True)

assert k.is_integer
assert k.is_real
```

What if I want to do the the same for an [`IndexedBase`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/tensor/indexed.html#sympy.tensor.indexed.IndexedBase) or a [`Function`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html#Function):

```
f = sy.Function('f', integer=True)
t = sy.Symbol('t')
assert f(t).is_integer  # AssertionError
```

```
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Idx
i = Idx('i')
A = IndexedBase('A', integer=True)
#  __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'integer'
assert A[i].is_integer
```

But neither of these work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The old-style assumptions are implemented in the class constructor of the SymPy object through various mechanisms. This should be implemented for every SymPy class separately. Some classes simply do not have this implementation available and you can't use it.

I suggest to use the new-style assumptions, where predicates are not declared on object construction:

```
In [1]: A = IndexedBase("A")

In [2]: with assuming(Q.positive(A[i])):
   ...:     print ask(Q.real(A[i]))
   ...:     
True

In [3]: with assuming(Q.positive(f(x))):
   ...:     print ask(Q.real(f(x)))
   ...:     
True
```

That is, you create a `with assuming( ... )` block, inside of it the assumptions declared inside `assuming` are assumed to hold. The assumptions in `ask( ... )` are then queried by logical deduction.

Unfortunately the new-style assumptions are not yet implemented in many of SymPy's algorithms (for example, `solve` will probably ignore them).

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntactic sugar for `Function` or `Indexed`, but you can still add assumptions by subclassing them. `Function('f')` creates a subclass of `Function` called `f`. You can use

```
class f(Function):
    is_integer = True
```

to create a subclass with `is_integer` set to True.

For `IndexedBase`, you'll want to subclass `Indexed`, which is the class that gets created when you do `A[i]`.

```
In [11]: i = Idx('i')

In [12]: class IntegerIndexed(Indexed):
   ....:     is_integer = True
   ....:

In [13]: IntegerIndexed("A", i)
Out[13]: A[i]

In [14]: IntegerIndexed("A", i).is_integer
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `is_indexed` is just a property that resolves to a lookup in the `._assumptions` member dictionary, so there's no guarantee that internal code will see the extra member

Comment: And setting `_assumptions` manually is not a great idea, because if you set `integer=True` you also have to set `real=True` and `rational=True`, plus whatever else that may imply

Comment: @Eric no you don't. You can check yourself, for objects above, `is_real` is set to True automatically.